# Page not deleting from DB/Gridview ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having problems with my ASP.NET Web application:

I have a Gridview that shows the rows of the "Pages" table on a mdb database; next to the id and the titles are two buttons, Edit and Delete. While the edit button works perfectly, the delete one won't work. I've put breakpoints at the beginning of the delPagina (delete page) method and it seems that such method does not run at all. This is the Gridview Code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdPagine" CssClass="table table-condensed"     BackImageURL="../media/img/hbg.png" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"     OnRowDeleting="delPagina">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="ID" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="titolo" HeaderText="Titolo" />
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <a href="EditPagina.aspx?idPag=<%# Eval("id") %>" class="btn btn-warning">Modifica</a>
            <asp:Button ID="delBut" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-danger"   CommandName="Delete" Text="Elimina" />
            </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And the delPagina method:

```
 public int delPagina(int _id)
    {
        Data.DB.OleDbDatabase db = new Data.DB.OleDbDatabase();
        string query = "DELETE FROM pagine WHERE id="+ _id;
        return db.EseguiNonQuery(query);
    }
```

The Event:

```
protected void delPagina(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
            int id = int.Parse(this.grdPagine.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Text);
            int b = new PaginaService().delPagina(id);
            List<Pagina> pag = new PaginaService().mlistapagine();
            this.grdPagine.DataSource = pag;
            this.grdPagine.DataBind();
    }
```

Sorry if my terminology is a bit off but this is kind of a new word for me.
Thanks in advance

Edit: When i click on the button there is a page refresh but no gridview is shown, so i have to refresh again manually.

Comment: Add click event in your button.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **RowCommand** and **CommandArgument**, Please look to following code sample

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdPagine" CssClass="table table-condensed"     BackImageURL="../media/img/hbg.png" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  OnRowCommand=grdPagine_RowCommand"    OnRowDeleting="delPagina">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="ID" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="titolo" HeaderText="Titolo" />
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <a href="EditPagina.aspx?idPag=<%# Eval("id") %>" class="btn btn-warning">Modifica</a>
            <asp:Button ID="delBut" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-danger"   CommandName="Delete" Text="Elimina" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("id") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And in code behind declare

```
protected void grdPagine_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
            {
int id = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            int b = new PaginaService().delPagina(id);
            List<Pagina> pag = new PaginaService().mlistapagine();
            this.grdPagine.DataSource = pag;
            this.grdPagine.DataBind();

}

}
```

Hopefully the above code solves your problem

Comment: Unfortunately, the code above does not work. I also forgot to mention that when i click on the Delete button the page refreshes but there is no Gridview so i have to manually refresh again.

Comment: Please share your code both .aspx and .cs, we have to look why your gridview is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code there is no click event in delBut button

you can use `RowCommand` event in gridview since your buttons `CommandName="Delete"`